# Is there a forum/StackExchange site for discussing Free Software?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I know that this probably isn't a good place to ask this, but I can't really think of another. I have questions about Free Software theory and opinions on how to create SaaS sites which incorporate freedom. Where can I ask this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't yet a Stack Exchange site for this. There used to be [proposal for such as site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13558/free-open-source-software-projects), but due to inactivity it was deleted. It's not really a wide enough topic area for an entire SE site.

[The correct place for the SE part of this is [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).]

Comment: That proposal is now deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://unix.stackexchange.com/